# Linking database column to dropdown control in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

I am using c# with asp.net and SQL Server 2005 as backend.  I want to use dropdown list control in a form to populate a textbox.  The dropdown control is linked to a column in the database.  How can I code this in c#?

Comment: a quick search would show you the many ways of doing this...

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 DropDownList1.datasource = list;
 DropDownList1.datBind();
 }

 protected void DropDownList1_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      TextBox1.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
 }
```

---

Or this

```
 protected void DropDownList1_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      TextBox t = new TextBox();
      t.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
      body.InnerHtml.add(t);
 }
```